# compilation error with template based factory and factory register helper

Tags: c++, templates, boost, compiler-errors, factory

I am having a problem with my template based factory and factory register:
factory.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_FACTORY
#define INCLUDED_FACTORY

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace common_utils {

template<class bT>
class Creator
{
public:
    virtual bT* create() = 0;
};

template <class bT>
struct CreatorPtr
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< Creator<bT> > type;
};

template <class bT, class cT>
class CreatorImpl : public Creator<bT>
{
public:
    virtual bT* create() { return new cT; }
};
```

factory_register.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_FACTORYREGISTER
#define INCLUDED_FACTORYREGISTER

#include <factory.h>

namespace common_utils {

template<class eT, class bT, class cT>
class FactoryRegister
{
public:
    FactoryRegister();
private:
    FactoryRegister(const FactoryRegister&)  {};
    FactoryRegister& operator=(const FactoryRegister&) {};
};

} // namespace common_utils
```

Now I get such compilation error:

> factory_register.h: In constructor ‘common_utils::FactoryRegister::FactoryRegister()’:
>   factory_register.h:15: error: expected `;' before ‘creator’
>   factory_register.h:16: error: ‘creator’ was not declared in this scope

It appears `CreatorPtr<bT〉：:type` is not recognized. Anyone can offer any insight?
Thanks.

Comment: Contd,
It appears this CreatorPtr<bT>::type is not recognized, does anyone see anything wrong there?

Comment: Original poster, the factory.h is only partly posted. The namespace is complete.

Comment: Ok, I'll guess: you need `typename` before `CreatorPtr<bT>::type` to specify that it is a dependent type.

Comment: Right one Casey! I got it right now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized (turned out to be a typo, based on comments). 